# How to write this XAML Storyboard in Code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Storyboard x:Key="CloseContentGrid">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="100"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

I want to change a Grid´s `Height` from `ActualHeight(100)` to `Zero` with this Animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(100,0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800)));
ContentGrid.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, animation);
```

Comment: So easy :) Thank you